# how to post restfull api to database via codeigniter with explode function?

Tags: php, json, api, rest, codeigniter

rest api request,
type:post,
request body:

```
{"data":"albert amstrong,18838327"}
```

If you see, i want to separate json object by "," and post to columns in my database...

my database name is data

how to make it as below.....

```
-----------------------------------
|id   | name           | number   |
-----------------------------------
|  1  |albert amstrong | 18838327 |
|     |                |          |
|     |                |          |
|     |                |          |
```

my php code

```
 public function index_post()
{
        $data = $this->post('data');
        $data = json_decode($data);
        $sth=$this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO kontak SET name=?, number=?');
        $sth->execute(array_map('trim', explode(',', $data->data)));
}
```

error message:

```
    <h4>An uncaught Exception was encountered</h4>

<p>Type: Error</p>
<p>Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::prepare()</p>
<p>Filename: /home/dokdafta/domains/donkeys.xyz/public_html/wa/application/controllers/api/Okaja.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 42</p>
```

Comment: why is the data in JSON not structured like the database, name and number separated?

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: Not really... the error message says that your database wrapper class doesn't have a method prepare(). I guess you'll have to ask the vendor of the framework or read its documentation.